# Select the fifth row for each individual using r

Tags: r, select, row

My dataframe looks like this :

```
ID    x1    x2
1     23    12
1     13    9
1     ..    ..
1
1
1
1
...
2
2
2
2
2
2
...
```

Repeated measurements for individual. I would like to generate a dataframe by selecting only the fifth observation for each individual. It seems easy, but I just could not figure it out the proper way. Thanks for any help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `slice` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   slice(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

One method in base R is to directly employ the split-apply-combine concept. First `split` the data.frame into a list of data.frames by ID. Second pull the fifth row out of each data.frame with `lapply` and `[`, and finally `rbind` the results together with `do.call`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) x[5,]))
  id values
a  a      5
b  b      5
c  c      5
d  d      5
e  e      5
f  f      5
g  g      5
```

the value of the val column is built to represent the row number.

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(id=rep(letters[1:7], each=10), values=rep(1:10))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `data.table` would be

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(df)[, .SD[5], by=ID]
```